# How can I cast types using a derived class as generic type in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, types

I am implementing a generic Tree as follow:

I have a `Node` class defined as:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public Node<T>? Parent;
    public readonly Tree<T> Children;
    public T? Data;

    public Node() => Children = new(this);
}
```

And a `Tree` class defined as:

```
public class Tree<T> : List<Node<T>>
{
    protected Node<T>? _owner = null;

    public Tree() { }
    public Tree(Node<T>? owner) => _owner = owner;

    public new void Add(Node<T> node) {
        base.Add(node);
        node.Parent = _owner;
    }
}
```

Then I have a `DerivedData` class that will be used to specify the generic type, implemented as:

```
public interface IDataRow { }

public abstract class BaseData : IDataRow { }

public class DerivedData : BaseData { }
```

The problem comes when I want to use it.

```
public class Program
{
    public Program()
    {
        Node<BaseData> node = new Node<DerivedData>(); // This does not compile

        Tree<BaseData> tree = new()
        {
            node
        };
    }
}
```

The assignment `Node<BaseData> node = new Node<DerivedData>();` does not compile because it cannot implicitly convert `Node<DerivedData>` to `Node<BaseData>`.

How can I achieve this?

I tried implementing covariant and contravariant interfaces to be implemented by `Node` class

```
public interface INodeIn<in T> { }
public interface INodeOut<out T> { }
public interface INode<T> : INodeIn<T>, INodeOut<T> { }

public class Node<T> : INode<T> { ... }
```

Then rewrite my main rutine as:

```
public Program()
{
    INodeOut<BaseData> node = new Node<DerivedData>(); // Now this works...

    Tree<BaseData> tree = new()
    {
        node // ...but this fails
    };
}
```

When I change the data type of `Tree.Add(Node<T> node)` method to be `Tree.Add(INodeOut<T> node)`, other two new errors appear because `INodeOut` does not contain a definition of Parent. By adding that definition neither works.

Comment: Deriving from `List<T>` is rarely a good idea. And this is no exception. A tree not really is-a List, is it?

Comment: @Fildor bring the link fildor

Comment: And as always: while `DerivedData` inherits `BaseData`, `Node<DerivedData` **does not** inherit `Node<BaseData`. They are two unrelated types, that are not mutually assignable. Why aren't they all `Node<IDataRow>`?

Comment: You know it,  Michael.

Comment: ok so i do it [Why not derrive from List<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/982149)

Comment: I'm on the cell phone rn, so don't have my "usual suspects" at hand. Thx Michael.

Comment: What is the purpose of `BaseData` and `DerivedData` here?